# Assignment from incompatible pointer type in (c)

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my struct,

```
typedef struct radixNode *radixPtr;
struct radixNode{
 int permission;
 int end;
 fileType type;
 radixPtr link[ASCII_SIZE];
};
```

I'm allocating memory for radixPtr,

```
radixPtr q;
q= createRadixNode();
```

And when I try to do this

```
q->link[index] = createRadixNode;
```

gcc gives warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type in c

Here is the allocate memory function

```
radixPtr createRadixNode () {
 radixPtr radix_node = (radixPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct radixNode));
 int i;

 if(radix_node == NULL) {
   perror("There is no memory to create radix node");
   exit(1);
 }

 radix_node->end = -1;
 for (i = 0; i < ASCII_SIZE; ++i) {
     radix_node->link[i] = NULL;
 }
 return radix_node;
}
```

I can't find a way to solve this. All things looks good. 
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you mean `q->link[index] = createRadixNode();` instead of `q->link[index] = createRadixNode;`? And don't cast the result of `malloc` and family

Comment: `q->link[index] = createRadixNode;` -->> `q->link[index] = createRadixNode();`

Comment: What a foolish mistake. Thank you!

Comment: why doesn't gcc give error like createRadixNode doesn't declared ?

Comment: @Abraam , I think that it is because the name of a function "decays" to a pointer that points to the function's address. So, `createRadixNode` is equal to `&createRadixNode`. The address of the function is used in several places like when using function pointers and multithreading(third argument of `pthread_create`) etc

Comment: @CoolGuy , I agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is

```
q->link[index] = createRadixNode();
```

instead of

```
q->link[index] = createRadixNode;
```

This will fix this issue. BTW, [don't cast the result of `malloc`(and family) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).